# Лишняя запятая? (2)

Tags: пунктуация

**Снаружи все дома разные, и все похожи друг на друга.**

Так — в изданной книге. На каком основании стоит запятая, не могу сообразить? Здесь ведь *снаружи* — общий элемент. Вероятно, автор имел в виду какое-то другое смысловое членение? Или просто недогляд корректора?

Comment: Наверное, на основании разумности. Например: Снаружи все дома одинаковые и  похожи друг на друга. Здесь запятая точно не нужна.

Comment: @Sharon а если по Розенталю? Возможно, что-то связано с повтором слова? "Все, и все".

Comment: Здесь и по Розенталю можно ответить, но вы сначала объясните мне содержание: что означает "разные и одновременно похожие"?  Поему это не заинтересовало вас?

Comment: @Sharon в книге использовано более конкретное слово, чем "дома". Но менее понятное вне контекста. Поэтому, чтобы не раздувать вопрос, я слово заменил. А смысл и в таком случае ясен. Люди тоже, к примеру, все разные и все похожи. И снежинки все разные и похожи.

Comment: Ну если снежинки разные, то попробую ответить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Снаружи все дома разные, и все похожи друг на друга.***

Смысл такой: Снаружи все дома разные и в то же время все похожи друг на друга.

Если пропущено сочетание "в то же время", то неожиданный переход надо обозначить паузой.

Соответственно, союз И присоединительный, при желании можно даже тире поставить.